# How to compute the sum of the values of elements in a vector using cblas functions?

Tags: neural-network, caffe, blas, conv-neural-network, cblas

I need to sum all the elements of a matrix in caffe,

But as I noticed, the caffe wrapper of the cblas functions (`'math_functions.hpp'` & `'math_functions.cpp'`) is using **`cblas_sasum`** function as **`caffe_cpu_asum`** that computes the sum of the **absolute** values of elements in a vector.

Since I'm a newbie in cblas, I tried to find a suitable function to get rid of **absolute** there, but it seems that there is no function with that property in cblas.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do so using cblas functions, though it is a bit of an awkward way.

What you need to do is to define an "all 1" vector, and then do a dot product between this vector and your matrix, the result is the sum.

Let `myBlob` be a caffe Blob whose elements you want to sum:

```
vector<Dtype> mult_data( myBlob.count(), Dtype(1) );
Dtype sum = caffe_cpu_dot( myBlob.count(), &mult_data[0], myBlob.cpu_data() );
```

This trick is used in the [implementation of `"Reduction"` layer](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/reduction_layer.cpp#L29-L55).

---

To make this answer both GPU compliant, one need to allocate a *`Blob`* for `mult_data` and not a `std::vector` (because you need it's `pgu_data()`):

```
vector<int> sum_mult_shape(1, diff_.count());
Blob<Dtype> sum_multiplier_(sum_mult_shape);
const Dtype* mult_data = sum_multiplier_.cpu_data();
Dtype sum = caffe_cpu_dot( myBlob.count(), &mult_data[0], myBlob.cpu_data() );
```

For GPU, (in a `'.cu'` source file):

```
vector<int> sum_mult_shape(1, diff_.count());
Blob<Dtype> sum_multiplier_(sum_mult_shape);
const Dtype* mult_data = sum_multiplier_.gpu_data();
Dtype sum;
caffe_gpu_dot( myBlob.count(), &mult_data[0], myBlob.gpu_data(), &sum );
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Summation of all the elements of an array is simple enough to be implemented by a single for-loop. You only need to use proper compile options to vectorise it with SIMD instructions.

For Blob in caffe, you could use `.cpu_data()` to get the raw pointer of the array and then use for-loop.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, actually, lots of cblas functions are doing too simple operations efficiently, but I have to do it in caffe without using a simple for loop to prevent poor performance. By the way, how can I loop over all the values in the data_ variable of a Blob in caffe?

Comment: for-loop has good performance on this. You could use proper compile options to vectorize it.