# How to loop over all the elements of a Blob variable in Caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

Working on a new loss layer in Caffe,

I have some values in **`diff_.cpu_data()`**, Lets name each element of that as **`Di`** :

Now, I want to compute this function for each **`Di`** :

[image]

and assign the result to the corresponding element in **`bottom[0]->mutable_cpu_diff()`** of the layer.

As you see, for the second term there is no need to loop over input and output variables ( **`diff_.cpu_data`** & **`bottom[0]->mutable_cpu_diff()`** respectively), while in the first term, I need to access the value of each element in input variable, then of course I need to assign the result of the function to the corresponding element of the output variable, If they were 2-D array, obviously I could do something like this:

[image]

But as you know, those variables are 4-D arrays and it is not clear for me how to do that.

Should I use **`Offset()`** function or something like that to loop over all the elements of those variables similar to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/caffe-users/loop$20over$20blob%7Csort:relevance/caffe-users/X1lexxIq2-0/IF1QSO_yvo0J)?

Could someone please explain it to me or refer me to a useful reference?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should store the result of the second term (1/N^2 \sum_i D_i) to a local variable.  As you [already know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714405/1714410), this sum can be computed using `caffe_cpu_dot`.

So your code may look something like:

```
vector<Dtype> mult_data( diff_.count(), Dtype(1) );
const Dtype* Di = diff_.cpu_data();
Dtype const_sum = caffe_cpu_dot( diff_.count(), &mult_data[0], Di );
Dtype N = diff_.count();
const_sum /= N*N; // divide by N^2
```

Now you can loop over all items (assuming `bottom[0]->count()==diff_.count()`):

```
Dtype* bottom_diff = bottom[0]->mutable_cpu_diff();
for (int i=0; i<diff_.count(); i++) {
  bottom_diff[i] = 2*Di[i]/N - const_sum;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want something more "blas"-like:

```
caffe_copy(diff_.count(), Di, bottom_diff);  // copy Di to bottom_diff
caffe_scal(diff_.count(), Dtype(2.0/N), bottom_diff);  // bottom_diff is now (2/N)*Di
caffe_add_scalar(diff_.count(), -const_sum, bottom_diff);  // subtract the second term from all the elements.
```

Comment: Perfect solution, many thanks. Just let me mention that before caffe_scal(diff_.count(), 2.0/N, bottom_diff); it's better to define Dtype alpha = 2.0/N; and then call it like: caffe_scal(diff_.count(), alpha, bottom_diff); to prevent any type mismatch. Thank you again.

Comment: Just a little question. when I use Dtype const_sum = caffe_cpu_dot( diff_.count(), &mult_data[0], Di ); in Backward_cpu it works well, but when I convert it into gpu mode: Dtype const_sum; 
    caffe_gpu_dot( diff_.count(), &mult_data[0], Di, &const_sum); in Backward_gpu, I got CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR. Do you know why?

Comment: @Ali when you convert to GPU, do you put all the code in a different .cu file?

Comment: Yes. I do. Should I convert const Dtype* Di = diff_.cpu_data(); into const Dtype* Di = diff_.gpu_data(); ? I don't think so.